# Filtering items by multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Filtering items by title, created_at dates, but one of them would be empty and it raises an error, how could I handle that?

```
where("country_translations.title ILIKE ? AND country_translations.created_at > ? AND country_translations.created_at < ?", "%#{search[:title]}%", search[:created_at_gt], search[:created_at_lt])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
YourModel.where(filter_by_translations_title).where(filter_by_translations_created)

def filter_by_translations_title
  ['country_translations.title ILIKE ?', search[:title]] if search[:title].present?
end
#...add rest of methods here
```

Chaining `#where` will join all queries via `AND`. This way will allow you add as many sub quesries as you want, and control their behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain your `where` clauses quite easily.

```
@results = Model.all
@results = @results.where('country_translations.title ILIKE ?', "%#{search[:title]}%") if search[:title].present?
```

If you're using Postgres you can also use a regex instead of ILIKE to get rid of this `%#{}%` stuff.

```
@results = @results.where('country_translations.title ~* ?', search[:title]) if search[:title].present?
```

and so on for your other fields.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you want to handle that.

First of all, I will decompose the query into multiple `where`s, that default to an AND operation. This is for readability:

```
Model.where("country_translations.title ILIKE ?", "%#{search[:title]}%")
     .where("country_translations.created_at > ?", search[:created_at_gt])
     .where("country_translations.created_at < ?", search[:created_at_lt])
```

You could either pass default values using the `||` operator, like this:

```
Model.where("country_translations.title ILIKE ?", "%#{search[:title] || ''}%")
     .where("country_translations.created_at > ?", search[:created_at_gt] || Time.now)
     .where("country_translations.created_at < ?", search[:created_at_lt] || Time.now)
```

or you can split this into three filters that have to be applied only when needed:

```
query = Model.all
query = query.where("country_translations.title ILIKE ?", "%#{search[:title]}%") if search[:title]
query = query.where("country_translations.created_at > ?", search[:created_at_gt]) if search[:created_at_gt]
query = query.where("country_translations.created_at < ?", search[:created_at_lt]) if search[:created_at_lt]

# query now is filtered only with present filters.
```

Comment: Last option loses on the concept of filtering the data..it not only hits db multiple times but load `all` first, then filter it gradually where previous data makes no sense to be load as it is anyway overwritten...setting default is certainly a good option

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon actually no. It does not hit the database until you _read_ the results. If you run it in a console, it **will** run many SQL commands, as the console is trying to print the result on each row. But when run in a script, the .where commands accumulate and create a single SQL query to be executed when needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can always use scopes in such case, they come handy almost everywhere

```
scope :filter_by_title, -> (title) { where('title ILIKE ?', "%#{title}%") if title.present? }
scope :filter_by_created_at_lt, -> (date) { where('created_at < ?', date) if date.present? }
scope :filter_by_created_at_gt, -> (date) { where('created_at > ?', date) if date.present? }
```

Then you can restructure the query as

```
Model.filter_by_title(search[:title])
     .filter_by_created_at_lt(search[:created_at_lt])
     .filter_by_created_at_gt(search[:created_at_gt])
```